# angularjs IE 11 Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-11

My angularjs(1.2.14) based application loads fine in IE10. However in IE11, the template url's are being blocked and the application is not rendered properly. Following is the error that I see in the console. I see that this is a known issue, but has been fixed (http://blog.jongallant.com/2013/09/scedelegate-plicy-insecurl.html#.VBiGz_ldWAg)

```
Error: [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.  URL: resources/partials/overview.start.html
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.14/$sce/insecurl?p0=resources%2Fpartials%2Foverview.start.html
at getTrusted (https://myserver.com/resources/lib/angular/1.2.14/angular.js:12849:11)
at Anonymous function (https://myserver.com/resources/lib/angular/1.2.14/angular.js:13535:9)
at Anonymous function (https://myserver.com/resources/lib/angular/1.2.14/angular-route.js:528:17)
at wrappedCallback (https://myserver.com/resources/lib/angular/1.2.14/angular.js:11046:15)
at wrappedCallback (https://myserver.com/resources/lib/angular/1.2.14/angular.js:11046:15)
at Anonymous function (https://myserver.com/resources/lib/angular/1.2.14/angular.js:11132:11)
at $eval (https://myserver.com/resources/lib/angular/1.2.14/angular.js:12075:9)
at $digest (https://myserver.com/resources/lib/angular/1.2.14/angular.js:11903:15)
at $apply (https://myserver.com/resources/lib/angular/1.2.14/angular.js:12179:13)
at Anonymous function (https://myserver.com/resources/lib/angular/1.2.14/angular.js:1341:9) 

Error: [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.  URL: template/accordion/accordion-group.html
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.14/$sce/insecurl?p0=template%2Faccordion%2Faccordion-group.html
at getTrusted (https://myserver.com/resources/lib/angular/1.2.14/angular.js:12849:11)
at Anonymous function (https://myserver.com/resources/lib/angular/1.2.14/angular.js:13535:9)
at compileTemplateUrl (https://myserver.com/resources/lib/angular/1.2.14/angular.js:6463:7)
at applyDirectivesToNode (https://myserver.com/resources/lib/angular/1.2.14/angular.js:6066:11)
at compileNodes (https://myserver.com/resources/lib/angular/1.2.14/angular.js:5668:9)
at compile (https://myserver.com/resources/lib/angular/1.2.14/angular.js:5601:7)
at applyDirectivesToNode (https://myserver.com/resources/lib/angular/1.2.14/angular.js:5995:13)
at compileNodes (https://myserver.com/resources/lib/angular/1.2.14/angular.js:5668:9)
at compile (https://myserver.com/resources/lib/angular/1.2.14/angular.js:5601:7)
at applyDirectivesToNode (https://myserver.com/resources/lib/angular/1.2.14/angular.js:6009:13)<div class="snap-drawer snap-drawer-left ng-scope"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error report contains a solution.
Link to the AngularJS KB: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$sce/insecurl?p0=template%2Faccordion%2Faccordion-group.html

Now quote from that page:

> Typically, this would occur if you're attempting to load an Angular
>   template from an untrusted source. It's also possible that a custom
>   directive threw this error for a similar reason.
>
> Angular only loads templates from trusted URLs (by calling
>   $sce.getTrustedResourceUrl on the template URL).
>
> By default, only URLs that belong to the same origin are trusted.
>   These are urls with the same domain, protocol and port as the
>   application document.
>
> The ngInclude directive and directives that specify a templateUrl
>   require a trusted resource URL.
>
> To load templates from other domains and/or protocols, either adjust
>   the whitelist/ blacklist or wrap the URL with a call to
>   $sce.trustAsResourceUrl.
>
> Note: The browser's Same Origin Policy and Cross-Origin Resource
>   Sharing (CORS) policy apply that may further restrict whether the
>   template is successfully loaded. (e.g. neither cross-domain requests
>   won't work on all browsers nor file:// requests on some browsers)

Comment: Yes, I saw that resolution. All my templates are in house to my application and not external resource. With that approach I need to whitelist all possible resources path within my own application, which could a bit overkill considering that the same application works fine in IE10, Chrome, Firefox etc.

Comment: You can try https://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools one of these machines with IE11 and see if this is something with IE11 or with your machine setup that blocks these urls.